# Scroll to the element on web page

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, automated-tests

I am working on automating test script using Python Selenium Webdriver.

I have buttons on the web page, but they are not visible in default window. We have to scroll the web page.

Can you please suggest the way to achieve this?

I have tried ActionChain, but after performing hover operation, I am still not able to click on correct element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
find_element_by_css_selector(".your_button_class");
```